# c# insert query executed successfully but data is not inserted in MS access databse

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I have one form having revise button is to update existing data in database. insert query executed successfully but data is not inserted

This is the code I use:

```
private void btnupdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int row = dataGridView1.RowCount;
            for (int i = 0; i < row - 1; i++)
            {
                String str = "INSERT INTO JDS_Data(E_JDS_ID,E_JDS_Revision,DesignSpec,Engine_Type,Record_date,CPH_Designer,Exp_Del_Week,Rev_Description,Name_of_mock_up,EPC_Drawing,Turbocharger_no_Type,Engine_Specific_Requirement,Description_of_Job,SF_No,Standard,Task_No,SF_revision,Part_family,Action_code,Remark,Modified_Date,UserName) values('" + txtjobno.Text + "','" + comboBox1.SelectedItem + "','" + txtds.Text + "','" + txtenginetype.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "','" + txtcphdesigner.Text + "','" + txtexpweek.Text + "','" + txtrevdescription.Text + "','" + txtmockup.Text + "','" + txtepcdwg.Text + "','" + txtturbono.Text + "','" + txtenginereq.Text + "','" + txtdespjob.Text + "','" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "','" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "','" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString() + "','" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString() + "','" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString() + "','" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString() + "','" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString() + "','" + DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + "','" + mdlconnection.user_name + "')";
                int dd = mdlconnection.excuteQuery(str);

            }


            MessageBox.Show("Data Revised Successfully..!!!");



        }
        catch (Exception e2)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("" + e2.Message);
        }


        int rw = dataGridView2.RowCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < rw - 1; i++)
        {
            String str = "INSERT INTO JDS_files(E_JDS_ID,SF_NO,PATH,Filename) values('" + txtjobno.Text + "','" + dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "','" + dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "','" + dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString() + "')";
            int dd = mdlconnection.excuteQuery(str);
        }
        btnupdate.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: Do you open a transaction?

Comment: I am not understand ?

Comment: I am first open existing record then update it in database

Comment: If you have an open transaction until you commit the database will not be updated

Comment: what i need to change it in code ..i didint found any open transaction

Comment: Ok. So forget my question. The problem is another.

Comment: your code suggests that you are trying to `INSERT` twice. I don't see an `UPDATE` operation here at all. Am i right to presume that your code should update a record if it exists, or insert it if it doesnt?

Comment: Sorry its my mistake I am going to insert new record when i click on revise.i know i have written insert operation.i will update my question .

Comment: is E_JDS_ID a primary key?

Comment: yes it is primary key

Comment: i expect its to do with you trying to insert your PK manually. Ideally you want to let the database handle this so that you cant make mistakes. I expect you could be trying to insert a duplicate PK. The fact that your program says `"Data Revised Successfully..!!!` suggests to me that you are trying to update an existing record by inserting it.

Comment: so can you please suggest what should i do ?

Comment: I have remove the primary key but yet its not inserting the record

Comment: Check if there's a copy of the Access db on the bin/debug or bin/release, it could be that the change is persisted there.

Comment: No there is no any copy of database